# Removing duplicates and add them in a single row

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have a dataset which looks like:

```
A B C
1 2 1
1 2 4
2 7 1
3 4 2
3 4 8
```

I want to add the duplicates and keep them in one row. The result would look like this :

```
A B C
1 2 5
2 7 1
3 4 10
```

I am unable to figure this out.

Comment: there are no duplicates in your dataset. i guess you mean duplicates only in column `A` and `B`, right? and for those sum `C`?

Comment: are you looking for `groupby` ?

Comment: Use: `df.groupby(['A','B']).sum().reset_index()`

Comment: How did you calculate the 3rd column in your final dataset?

Comment: @luigigi - Yes, that's correct. Thanks for the edit

Comment: @CanÇalışkan - Duplicates are in Column A and B. And then values of C are added for the duplicates.

Comment: Could you please explain how did you find 10?

Comment: 8+2 in the last two rows are added since values in columns A and B are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code for your expected result

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[1,2,1], [1,2,4], [2,7,1],[3,4,2],[3,4,8]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['A','B','C'])
sum_c =  df.groupby(['A','B']).sum().reset_index()
rmv_ind = sum_c.to_string(index=False)
print rmv_ind
```

Output:-

```
 A  B   C
 1  2   5
 2  7   1
 3  4  10
```